# How to transfer a selected file from a JFileChooser into a JButton that applies a code on it when it is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I am working on a GUI for an application that allows the transformation of an input XMI code to an output XMI code, based on some transformation rules. (I inserted a screenshot of the GUI.)

The transformation is implemented in a class other than the GUI class and it includes a `launch()` method to launch the transformation.

So in my GUI class, I implemented a `JButton` that I named `transform`, in the `addActionListener(new ActionListener())` method I called the `launch` method that enables the transformation and I added the required parameters for it, which are: ( the meta-model of the input file's path, the input XMI file's path, the meta-model of the output file's path, the output XMI file's path, the transformation directory's path, the transformation file's path)

The transformation button code is as follows:

```
transformer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
    
ATLLauncher atlLaunch = new ATLLauncher();

 atlLaunch.registerInputMetamodel("./mm/input.ecore");
 atlLaunch.registerOutputMetamodel("./mm/output.ecore");
 atlLaunch.launch("./mm/input.ecore", "./mo/inputInst.xmi", "./mm/output.ecore", "./mo/resultXMI.xmi", "./transformation/","MyTrans");  
 System.out.println("done!!");
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("nope");
        }
    }
});
```

The transformation works fine and an output file with the resulting XMI is created and is stored in the path that I specified in the parameters.

I implemented a file chooser to load the input file as well (the button named `Load file`) and it also displays the content of the input file into the `JTextField` that I created (called `input`).

The code for the file chooser is the following:

```
loader.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        openMe om = new openMe();
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
        filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
        
        try {
            //om.PickMe();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            textArea.read(br, null);
            br.close();
            textArea.requestFocus();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

What I want, however, is to be able to transfer (automatically) the file I chose using `Load file` into the `Transform` button to apply the transformation on it.

And once the transformation is done I want the output XMI file content to be displayed in the text field called `output`, besides that, I want the output file to be downloadable. It means when I press `Download` button I get to save it wherever I want on my PC.

The code for the `Download` button is as follows:

```
downloader.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser1 = new JFileChooser();
            chooser1.showSaveDialog(null);
            File f1 =chooser1.getSelectedFile();
            
            try {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
                String txt =outputfile.getText();
                fw.write(txt);
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    });
}
```

How can I achieve these transfers between different buttons?

The screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  I can't tell if you're asking a single question or multiple questions

Comment: JButtons allow you to provide an ActionListener that performs an action.  Modify your action listeners to do what you outlined in your questrion.

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli they are actually two questions, the whole application must be something that allows you to upload an xmi file, by pressing upload, it will get displayed, then it allows you to transform the file by pressing transform,  and the result will be displayed too, eventually, it will allow you to download the result as an output xmi file. 
What I want to know is how to transfer the uploaded file into the transform button action, then transfer the resulting xmi to the download button action. I hope it's clearer now!

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes, i am aware of that. However, i don't seem to understand the command or the line of code which will take the uploaded file and feed it to the transform button actionlistner, if this makes sense!

Comment: In your transform ActionListener, the atlLaunch.registerInputMetamodel is your loader.addActionListener filename and the atlLaunch.registerOutputMetamodel is your downloader.addActionListener filename (f1.getAbsolutePath()).  Your atlLaunch.launch String will have to be constructed with the filenames as well.